# Ubuntu Budgie freezes and requires hard reset, got journalctl stuff related to radeon

Tags: ubuntu, freeze, amd-radeon

This has been happening for a long time now, everything, including the cursor, freezes, and requires a hard reset (5 seconds on power button).

Recently, it's been getting unbearable, as when I use Godot it happens around 20 minutes into a session. This is what journalctl displays before the last reset: https://pastebin.com/i0hsyTNK

I can't work like this and I don't know where to start looking for an issue.